# Проблема при сборке Android studio 'android.support.design.widget

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Добавил в проект bottom navigation view, настроил его как обычно, но при сборке проекта появилась такая ошибка

```
The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.
```

Искал ответы на форумах, добавлял разные библиотеки, мигрировал проект в AndroidX но без толку. В стилях у меня всё от Material.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484988/the-given-artifact-contains-a-string-literal-with-a-package-reference-android-s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811204/how-to-fix-android-support-v4-content-in-androidx